# tilde expansion when evaluating $PATH

Tags: bash, portability, path-variables, tilde-expansion

On my system*

```sh
cd                                                 # move to home
mkdir tempdir
PATH="$PATH:~/tempdir"                             # put tempdir in path
touch tempdir/tempscript
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\necho h' > tempdir/tempscript # write script
chmod u+x tempdir/tempscript                       # make executable
tempscript                                         # execute
```

will find the script `tempdir/tempscript` and print `h`.

However, if we echo `$PATH`, we will see `~/tempdir` at the end of it, so it was *not* expanded. Which is what we expect to happen, since we put double quotes around the assignment.

I can't find any documentation however on why tilde expansion occurs when evaluating `$PATH`. (Note that the PATH variable still has the `~` in it.)

Is this portable behavior?

* Mac OS X w/ GNU bash 3.2

Comment: In `BASH` it is portable behavior.  Have a look at: [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)

Comment: @user3439894, that's true **IF NOT QUOTED**. Quoting prevents tilde expansion, even if assigning to a variable. That's explicitly in the docs you linked: "Each variable assignment is checked for *unquoted* tilde-prefixes"

Comment: @Charles Duffy, Okay I guess from now on I qualify everything I say! Yes it's portable when done so within the bounds of the rules and hence why I included the link in my first comment as I expect users to RT*M too!

Comment: @user3439894, ...but the OP explicitly demonstrated a quoted assignment. A reasonable reader could expect "this" to refer to the code given in that demonstration.-

Comment: @CharlesDuffy \@user3439894 You are both right in a way. I'll make the quotes part of it more explicit in my question.

Comment: BTW, when doing your testing, I'd suggest using a program other than the shell to execute the child program. Executing the program in a tilde-delimited path through `xargs` or a similar tool will have that effect.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, Okay I missed the quotes on the assignment in the OP! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not portable. If your operating system's `execl` call doesn't perform this expansion, programs that *aren't* bash will fail to find executables within the given directory.

Note that if you didn't quote the expansion, this would be safe:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/tempdir   # this is safe -- expansion happens before assignment
PATH="$PATH:~/tempdir" # this is not -- readers are required to expand
```

While it's generally a best practice to quote all shell expansions, this isn't necessary for assignments, which implicitly prevent string-splitting and glob expansion behaviors.

Comment: I didn't know that about assignments - thanks. Also, I just tried on a centos 6 system and it worked there as well. So perhaps it's undefined, but mostly consistent, behavior.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius Have a look at: [Literal tilde in PATH works poorly across programs.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2147)

Comment: removing the quotes made the difference in my case, nice